# Changing the database compatibility level

Tags: sql-server

I have successfully changed my database `compatibility_level` from 90 to 100. (ie, `SQL Server 2005` to `SQL Server 2008/R2`).

Now I am getting one doubt, due to this type of compatibility level changes, Will I face any problems in feature or any issues will comes to existing tables/functions/stored procedures ?

**Note:** `master,tempdb,model and msdb` all these are having compatibility level as 100 only.
But myDatabase is having 90 as comp-level. Now I have updated to 100.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to worry about the Compatibility Level of a database if you'll be restoring a backup of your database onto an older version of the server software. If all of your database servers are 2008 (100) or 2008 R2 (110) then you have nothing to worry about.

Raising the compatibility-level of a database won't break anything unless you're using deprecated or obsolete features, such as `ntext` instead of `nvarchar(MAX)`. SSMS should give you a warning or some set of messages if you raise the Compatibility Level and it detects a problem with your schema.

It won't upgrade your Sprocs, Views and other objects, however. You must audit those yourself. If you don't use Sprocs then you have nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Thanks Dai, 
But Dai, I have a table columns with ntext as datatype. But while updating/selecting records, I am not getting any errors or warnings.

Comment: `ntext` is still supported in SQL Server 2008, however according to this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx `ntext` will be removed from SQL Server 2014.